# Can we Apply K-means algorithm with Cosine similarity measure

Tags: clustering, k-means, high-dimensional, cosine-similarity

One of the most using algorithm for clustering text documents that represented by VSM is k-means this notes according to Agrawal(Text mining book 2016 2nd edition);

I would like to know if its possible to used Cosine Measure with K-means to measure similarity and clustering Docs that represented in high dimensional vectors (BOW),

so, Is possible to used **Cosine similarity** and what is the formula of this metric when applying under high dimensional representation to give an effort measures?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cosine is equivalent to squared Euclidean distance on normalized data.

So yes, you can use k-means with cosine (see "spherical k-means"). Or you just scale your data to unit length, and use regular k-means.